# Routing: Forward slashes are still encoded when using a double-asterisk (**) catch-all parameter syntax

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to use **url parameter with forward slash in it** (for better looking url).

I've set up routing as shown in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2) with double asterisk:

```cs
mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
    name: "processRequest",
    template: "{lang}/{**path}",    
    defaults: new { controller = "DisplayContent", action = "ProcessRequest", lang = "en" });
```

Route is picked up and parameters are passed correctly to action if I enter url like www.example.com/en/s/link.
The problem arises when I try to generate links based on this route.

```cs
Url.RouteUrl("processRequest", new { lang = 'en', path = "s/link" })
```

gives

> */en/s%2flink*

The same thing happens when I use anchor tag helper in razor.

```html
<!-- GetQueryParameters is a method that returns query parameters as Dictionary<string, string> -->
<a asp-route="processRequest" asp-all-route-data="@ViewContext.GetQueryParameters()">Test</a>
<a asp-route="processRequest" asp-route-lang="en" asp-route-path="s/link">Test</a>
```

Both of these sets href to

> */en/s%2flink*.

Is it possible to generate these links using helpers or do I have to settle with manually creating string and setting `href` without using tag helpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I got it working. Changed so many things (multiple routing paths, anchor tag helper calls).
But one thing I can say for sure that breaks this is removing compatibility version.

```cs
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
```

I had removed this at some point, but after adding it back the links are created as I want.